# Convert existing Electron codebase to React so it works with mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, electron

Is it possible to take a desktop app made with Electron js and somehow make it work on mobile? I read it's possible to convert React applications to Electron applications and I was wondering if it's possible to do it the other way around. It's likely it might not be possible to convert it 1:1 because of native functions etc. probably.

I haven't tried anything because I doubt it's possible - I just want confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what it does. If the functionality would work equally well on a website inside a browser then yes. You'll just need to store data somewhere else than on user's file system. But if the electron app uses native or node features, like accesses local files, then probably not so easily.

Comment: Ah thanks for that. Do you know about whether there's tools/ existing services out there to aid the transformation of code that utilizes native features on desktop to mobile? (e.g some fs alternative for mobile, I've heard about browserify but don't know whether it can work for this)

Comment: Browserify can transform node modules into code that works in browser too, but it cannot circumvent the browser safety rules. Like preventing code from wiping out files on your local machine. What does the app do? Most likely you need to create a server API to create an account and store data serveside, and then use browser to log in and get that data.